# LG-Ally won't charge

Tags: battery, charging

My LG Ally is out of battery and won't charge at all.  I know the outlet is working.  It's charged in the past just fine..

I gave it like 30 minutes plugged in, and power wouldn't do anything.  No type of light or indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different USB cable.  Or try plugging it into a computer to check if it's the cable.

Comment: Tried a different cable, still didnt work

Comment: I wonder if the port is broken :(

Comment: I finally got it by pulling out battery and putting it back in!  Thanks for the help im upvoting and counting as answer

Comment: Very weird!  Glad you figured it out.